# Finding the second derivative of the function from the implict function theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

I have $(f_1, f_2) : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and say at $0$ the Hessian say at $(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) = (a_1, .., a_{n-2}, b_1, b_2)$ we have $(f_1(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}), f_2(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})) = (0,0)$ and
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \partial f_1/\partial y_1 (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) & \partial f_1/\partial y_2 (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) \\ \partial f_2/\partial y_1 (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) & \partial f_2/\partial y_2 (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) \end{pmatrix}
$$
is invertible where we denote the $n$ variables by $(x_1, .., x_{n-2}, y_1, y_2)$. Then we can apply the implicit function theorem to obtain $g:U \to \mathbb{R}^2$, where $U$ is an open neighborhood of $\mathbf{a}$, such that $(f_1(\mathbf{x}, g(\mathbf{x}), f_2(\mathbf{x}, g(\mathbf{x})) = (0, 0)$ on $U$.

I want to find a higher partial derivatives of $g$. If there was only one function $f_1$ then I could take a derivative of $f_1$, set it to $0$ and get an expression for $\partial f_1/ \partial x_i$ and then take a derivative again. What can I do when there is more than one function as in this case? Thank you.

Comment: I actually wrote [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3600628/568204) on this a while back. It's essentially the same result as what's below, modulo some notational differences.

Comment: You are wrong, you will not find a single $g:U \to \mathbf{R}$ but a pair $(g_1, g_2):U \to \mathbf{R}$ such that $f_1(x, g_1(x)) = 0$ and $f_2(x, g_2(x)) = 0$ for $x \in U.$ In general, if $f:\mathbf{R}^{p+q} \to \mathbf{R}^p$ then the last $q$ variables can be represented as a function of the first $p$ variables (in other words, the implicit function takes values $\mathbf{R}^p \to \mathbf{R}^q).$

Comment: it was just a typo thanks. but it looks like you are wrong as well

Answer (score 1):

The expression of the second differential is in general tedious. I write it in a general setting below.

Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces, $\mathcal{U}\subset E$ an open set and $f\in\mathcal{C}^k(\mathcal{U},F)$ for some $k\geq 2$. We assume that $E=E'\times E'$ and that the partial differential $\mathrm{d}_2f(x_0):=\mathrm{d}f(x_0)_{\vert E''}\in\mathcal{L}(E'',F)$ is invertible for some $u_0\in\mathcal{U}$. By the implicit function theorem, there is a neighborhood $\mathcal{V}'\times\mathcal{V}''\subset\mathcal{U}$ of $x_0$ such that $f(x',x'')=\beta:=f(x_0)$ if and only if $x''=g(x')$ for some $g\in\mathcal{C}^k(\mathcal{V}'',F)$. Differentiating this equation for a fixed $\beta\in F$ yields
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{d}_1f(x',g(x'))+\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))\circ\mathrm{d}g(x')&=0
\end{align*}
and thus
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{d}g(x')&=-\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))^{-1}\circ\mathrm{d}_1f(x',g(x'))\in\mathcal{L}(E',E'').
\end{align*}

We now look for an expression of $\mathrm{d}^2g(x')\in\mathcal{L}(E'\times E',E'')$ (which makes sense as $k\geq 2$). We let $h\in E'$ and
\begin{align*}
 L&:E'\ni x\longmapsto L(x'):=\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))^{-1}\in\mathcal{L}(F,E''),\\
 %
 M&:E'\ni x\longmapsto M(x'):=\mathrm{d}_1f(x',g(x'))[h]\in F
\end{align*}
so that
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{d}L(x')&\in\mathcal{L}(E',\mathcal{L}(F,E''))\simeq\mathrm{Bil\,}(E'\times F,F),\\
 %
 \mathrm{d}M(x')&\in\mathcal{L}(E',F).
\end{align*}
For all $k\in E'$, we have
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{d}\big(L(x')\circ M(x')\big)[k]&=(\mathrm{d}L(x')[k])\circ M(x')+L(x')\circ(\mathrm{d}M(x')[k])\in E''.
\end{align*}
Now we compute for all $(h,\ell)\in E'\times F$:
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{d}L(x')&=-\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))^{-1}\circ\bigg[\mathrm{d}_1\big(\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))\big)+\mathrm{d}_2\big(\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))\big)\circ\mathrm{d}g(x')\bigg]\circ\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))^{-1},\\
 %
 \mathrm{d}L(x')[h,\ell]&=-\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))^{-1}\bigg[\mathrm{d}_1\big(\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))\big)\Big[\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))^{-1}[h],\ell\Big]\\
 &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad+\mathrm{d}_2\big(\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))\big)\Big[\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))^{-1}[h],\mathrm{d}g(x')[\ell]\Big]\bigg],\\
 %
 %
 \mathrm{d}M(x')[k]&=\mathrm{d}_1\big(\mathrm{d}_1f(x',g(x'))\big)[h,k]+\mathrm{d}_2\big(\mathrm{d}_1f(x',g(x'))\big)\Big[h,\mathrm{d}g(x')[k]\Big].
\end{align*}
We finally obtain for all $(h,k)\in E'\times E'$ (replacing $\ell$ by $\mathrm{d}_1f(x',g(x'))[h]\in F$):
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{d}^2g(x')[h,k]&=\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))^{-1}\bigg[\mathrm{d}_1\big(\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))\big)\Big[\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))^{-1}[h],\mathrm{d}_1f(x',g(x'))[h]\Big]\\
 &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad+\mathrm{d}_2\big(\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))\big)\Big[\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))^{-1}[h],\mathrm{d}g(x')\big[\mathrm{d}_1f(x',g(x'))[h]\big]\Big]\bigg]\\
 %
 &-\mathrm{d}_2f(x',g(x'))^{-1}\bigg[\mathrm{d}_1\big(\mathrm{d}_1f(x',g(x'))\big)[h,k]+\mathrm{d}_2\big(\mathrm{d}_1f(x',g(x'))\big)\Big[h,\mathrm{d}g(x')[k]\Big]\bigg]\in E''.
\end{align*}

In your case, you have to replace differentials by partial derivatives and matrices.