# Show that $\partial ^2 y / \partial x \partial y = 0$ for implicit function $f(x,y(x))$?

Tags: partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

I find **Implicit function theorem** (limited to scalar function) both fascinating and a bit puzzling. Simply said, total derivative of some $f(x,y(x))$ according to $x$ is:

$$ \frac{d f(x,y(x)) }{ dx } = f_{x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} + f_{y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0$$

It is straight forward to see, that such total derivative of $f(x,y(x))$ can be expressed through partial derivative:

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = - \frac{f_{x}(x, y(x))}{f_{y}(x,y(x))} \tag {1}$$

where for brevity $f_{x} = \frac{\partial f(x,y(y))}{\partial x}$ and $f_{y} = \frac{\partial f(x,y(y))}{\partial y}$

*So far, so good*. Now lets try to continue by taking partial derivative with respect to $y$. This can naturally happen when one needs to evaluate implicit function $f(x,y(x))$ for variable $y$ at variable $x$, it's first derivative $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ and naturally one would expect second derivative $\frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial ^2 x}$ and $\frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial x \partial y}$ to exist, e.g. for calculating Hessian matrix.

**Case 1: apply quotient rule on {1}**

One could blindly do the following in order to obtain $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ to get $\frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial x \partial y}$:

$$\frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial x \partial y} = - \frac{\partial (\frac{f_{x}}{f_{y}})}{\partial y}$$ which holds, if higher derivatives of $f_x$ and $f_y$ exists.

**Case 2: analyze where the expression becomes constant**

Obviously $\frac{\partial y}{\partial y} = 1$. This happens within $\frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial y \partial x}$ and since $\frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial y \partial x}$, then it is expected to happen for any mixed second-order partial derivative.

This way, one should have always $\frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial y \partial x} = 0$ for an implicit function, since deriving $\frac{\partial y}{\partial y} = 1$ is the derivation of a constant, thus 0.

### **Question**

Which of the 2 cases is wrong and why?

### **More details**

To provide more details, but still keep the question general, lets assume the form of $f(x,y(x))$, to provide some *visual clues*.

$$f(x,y(x)) = e^{(x+y)} + x + y = 0$$

### **Background** (to give the equations intuitive motivation related to experimental observations)

Variables $x$ and $y$ are physical quantities (current, voltage). $f(x,y(x)) = 0$, thus this function is used to evaluate the quantities $x$ and $y$ only. For instance, I need the value of $y$ for $x=c$, then I evaluate $f(c,y) = 0$ to get $y$. This also means, that when one variable changes (e.g. $x$) then $y$ changes as well. Therefore, when I calculate derivatives, then naturally I take $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}$, because that is what I observe as a derivative at the level of the physical system (e.g. lowering current, rises the voltage). This means, that in the Jacobian and Hessian I expect to see $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}$, rather than $\frac{\partial f(x,y(x))}{\partial y}$.

Comment: You are abbreviating far too much. Eqn (1) should read $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=-\frac{f_x(x,y(x))}{f_y(x,y(x)}$, it only holds when we substitute in for $x$ the value $y(x)$ of the implicitly defined function. So both sides are univariate functions of $x$, no $y$ occurs in either.

Comment: This makes no sense. Instead of $y(x)$, write the implicitly defined function as $y=g(x)$, and I hope you'll see that it's quite meaningless to ask about the derivative of $g(x)$ or $g'(x)$ with respect to $y$...

Comment: @ancientmathematician I have corrected the eq. 1

Comment: @HansLundmark "Makes no sense" is the puzzling part, since these expressions still appear in Hessian. Does "meaningless" means the $\partial y / \partial y = 1$ or $0$ since $g(x)$ is not a function of $y$? There is this excellent answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3600407/hessian-matrix-of-the-function-defined-with-implicit-function-theorem, which I think hints the same thing as you, but I am getting lost in notation, when the expression in square brackets apperar

Comment: The Hessian of **what**, exactly? The Hessian of a one-variable function $g(x)$ is just the $1 \times 1$ matrix containing the single entry $g''(x)$. The Hessian of a two-variable function $f(x,y)$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix containing the second partial derivatives of $f$. I think your confusion comes from writing the implicitly defined function as $y(x)$, which causes you to mix up this one-variable function with the independent variable $y$ appearing as an argument to the two-variable function $f(x,y)$. So, as I already said, **don't** write the function like that. Call it $g(x)$ instead.

Comment: Also, note that in the answer that you linked to, the variable $x$ is actually not a single variable, but an abbreviation for $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, so in that case it makes more sense to ask about the Hessian of the implicitly defined function (but with partial derivatives with respect to the $x_k$ variables, not with respect to $y$!). In your own question, it's understood that $x$ and $y$ are just scalar variables (real numbers), right?

Comment: And regarding $\partial y/\partial y$, you need to ask yourself exactly what you *mean* when you write that expression. If you mean $u'_y(x,y)$ where the two-variable function $u$ is defined by $u(x,y)=y$ (so that $y$ is an independent variable in a two-variable function), then of course the answer is $1$. But if you mean to differentiate the function that you've written “$y=y(x)$”, then the expression is meaningless, since that function is not a function of $y$ to begin with.

Comment: @HansLundmark Lets unpack your comments. 1) Hessian of $||F||_2^2$, where $F$ is a vector function, such that $F_1 = u_1(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, x_3, y_3, ...) = 0$. The $u_1$ is linear or affine function, therefore, when I take derivatives I arrive to expressions like $\tfrac{\partial x_1 }{ \partial y_1}$. I have on purpose revealed only the relevant details in my question, since I dont have a problem with the norm or vector function, but a specific expression, which is related to the scalar implicit function.

Comment: @HansLundmark With your second and third comment I think I am getting closer to understanding my problem. To my understanding, and here you may correct me, once I set $x=x_0$, the $f(x,y(x))$ then evaluates to something like $y = g(x_0,y)$. Can you help me here to resolve the notion of $g(y)$, $y(x)$ in this particular case? I have added **More details** to illustrate what the function looks like.

Comment: I don't understand the stuff about $\lVert F \rVert_2^2$. And also the part after “once I set $x=x_0$” makes zero sense to me. I honestly have no idea at all what you're trying to do there, so I don't have anything sensible to say about it.

Comment: Regarding the **More details** part, you should first write $f(x,y)=e^{x+y}+x+y$ to define the two-variable function $f$. No $y(x)$ here yet, just the independent variable $y$! Then, under some conditions, the IFT gives you a one-variable function $g$ such that $f(x,g(x))=0$ for all $x$ in some interval. In other words, $e^{x+g(x)} + x + g(x) = 0$. And for the third time I advise you to **not** write $g(x)$ as $y(x)$, since that apparently will only confuse you. The derivative of this function $g$ is given by the formula $g'(x) = -f_x(x,g(x)) / f_y(x,g(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about the order.

$\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x\partial y}$ means $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}\right)$.  If you want to calculate it the other order (differentiate with respect to $x$ first), it is $\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial y\partial x}$.

Recall in the proof of symmetry of partials that we need to be able to change $x$ and $y$ independently (and the twice-differentiability of $f\colon U\to E$).  Now symmetry of partial derivatives $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,\dots)}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,\dots)}{\partial y\partial x}$ does not hold if $x,y$ are dependent in general.  For example, on $\mathbb{R}^+$ with local coordinate $x$, consider also another local coordinate $y=x^2$.  The two differential operators $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}$ do not commute: We have $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}=\frac1{2x}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$, so

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}
&=\frac1{2x}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}
\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac1{2x}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\\
&=\frac1{2x}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}
+\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac1{2x}\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\\
&=
\frac1{2x}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}
-\frac1{2x^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\\
\end{align*}
In other words, for any nonconstant twice-differentiable function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}f(x)-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(x)=-\frac1{2x^2}f'(x)\neq 0.
$$

Comment: I believe you are onto something here, I dont know who downvoted the answer. But excuse my lack of knowledge, but $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{d}{d x}$ are technically operators. Dont you then mean $\frac{d}{d x} \frac{d}{d y} x^2$ ? If I am wrong or I miss read your notation, please rewrite your answer, such that differentiation operators are separated from operands.

Answer (score -1):

Most confusion about partial derivatives can be cured by being explicit about which *function* you are taking partial derivative of.  So, what is the function $y$?  What are its parameters?

Perhaps you are talking about the function $y(x,f)$?

Then, indeed $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = -\frac{f_x}{f_y}$.  However, for this function, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}$ is a meaningless combination of symbols since $y$ is not one of its parameters.

Or, maybe, you mean function $y(x,y)$?

Now you can have a partial derivative with respect to $y$:  $\frac{\partial y}{\partial y} = 1$.  But, for this function,  $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0$.

Comment: I have added **More details** and also in question comments I have asked @HansLundmark to elaborate on $y(x,f)$ or $g(x)$ and such. I think you and Hans try to guide me the right way, but I somewhat fail to recognize the general case. May I ask to edit your answer and clearly state, what $y(x,f)$ or $y(y,x)$ would be in case of the provided $f(x,y(x))$? 

If it seems that I am asking for too specific answer (e.g. solving for specific $f(x,y(x))$) , then after I solve this issue, I will edit your answer (if necessary) to apply to general case. And of course accept it as correct answer.